# (WPF) UI best practices

Tags: .net, wpf

we are curring analyzing whether to implement a solution for a software application by using either WPF or WinForms.

Apart from that decision, I just wanted to ask whether someone of you has good resources in terms of UI design (i.e. layout) (papers, case studies, links, books...), preferably targeted to WPF. I do not necessarily intend usability rules in general (like accessibility etc..), but more specifically on how to organize the UI.

Like this: http://healthcare.codeplex.com/

The application is a business application, not an ERP system but it goes in that direction.

Thx a lot

Juri

Answer (score 3):

For UI design check out [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Main) from Infragistics. It´ s a user interface pattern browser with many useful patterns, descriptions, examples and so on.

**NOTE:** Quince is shutting down services on Saturday, October 31, 2015.

Answer (score 1):

As well as looking into MVVM, you may want to take a look at Josh Smith's excellent Podcatcher series on Code Project. These articles talk about how to create an application, and then to apply a top-notch UI on top of it using something that Josh calls structural skinning.

[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/podder1.aspx) to introductory article.
[Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/podder2.aspx) to article describing implementation of structural skinning.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Model View View-Model pattern (MVVM) - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Here are a few other interesting links

- Josh Smith's blog for WPF - http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/
- MVVM Foundation, A class library to implement MVVM for your apps - http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/

Comment: MVVM is interesting, but this goes more into the topic of decoupling UI from code etc...I was focusing more on design in terms of UI layout, positioning of controls like navigation menu on the right in terms of a tree structure etc..something like this. I should probably make my question a bit clearer. Thx anyway :)